# Haskell - Pattern match(es) are overlapped

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

```
test :: String -> String -> Int

test' x y n = n
test' "" (y:ys) n = error "error"
test' (x:xs) "" n = error "error"
test' (x:xs) (y:ys) n =
        if      x == y
        then    test'  xs ys n
        else    test'  xs ys (n+1)
test a b = test' a b 0
```

When I compile this, I get this output:

```
Warning: Pattern match(es) are overlapped
```

And the answer is always "0", which is not what I intended. What is the problem with the code and how to fix it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`test' x y n = n` will match for every call, the other patterns won't be considered. I think this case should be `test' "" "" n = n`. You get the same result if you move your original line at the **end** (when all other cases fail), but then you should write `test' _ _ n = n` which shows that you deliberately ignore some of the arguments.

**[Edit]**

A shorter solution would be:

```
test a b | length a == length b = sum $ map fromEnum $ zipWith (/=) a b
         | otherwise = error "error"
```

The `zipWith` expression generates a list of `Bool` which is `True` for every difference. The function `fromEnum` maps `False` to `0` and `True` to `1`.

Answer (score 7):

The patterns are tried in order. The first of your patterns for `test'` always matches, so that case is always used.  The first case should probably be

```
test' "" "" n = n
```

instead.