# Why are patterns overlapping in this example?

Tags: haskell

```
scheme.hs:184:1: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are overlapped
    In an equation for `eval':
        eval env (List (Atom "define" : List (Atom var : params) : body))
             =
             ...
        eval env
             (List (Atom "define" : DottedList (Atom var : params)
                                               varargs : body))
             =
             ...
        eval env (List (Atom "lambda" : List params : body)) = ...
        eval env (List (Atom "lambda" : DottedList params varargs : body))
             =
             ...
        ...
```

From the [Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 Hours](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Defining_Scheme_Functions) book. I do not know Haskell, but I do know some functional programming and despite that I can't figure out why those two patterns are overlapping.

Can anybody explain to me the above error? Thanks.

Edit: I thought the above snippet might be enough.

```
eval :: Env -> LispVal -> IOThrowsError LispVal
eval env val@(String _) = return val
eval env val@(Number _) = return val
eval env val@(Bool _) = return val
eval env (Atom id) = getVar env id
eval env (List [Atom "quote", val]) = return val
eval env (List [Atom "if", pred, conseq, alt]) =
    do result <- eval env pred
       case result of
             Bool False -> eval env alt
             otherwise -> eval env conseq
eval env (List [Atom "set!", Atom var, form]) =
    eval env form >>= setVar env var
eval env (List [Atom "define", Atom var, form]) =
    eval env form >>= defineVar env var
eval env (List (function : args)) = do
     func <- eval env function
     argVals <- mapM (eval env) args
     apply func argVals
eval env badForm = throwError $ BadSpecialForm "Unrecognized special form" badForm
eval env (List (Atom "define" : List (Atom var : params) : body)) =
     makeNormalFunc env params body >>= defineVar env var
eval env (List (Atom "define" : DottedList (Atom var : params) varargs : body)) =
     makeVarArgs varargs env params body >>= defineVar env var
eval env (List (Atom "lambda" : List params : body)) =
     makeNormalFunc env params body
eval env (List (Atom "lambda" : DottedList params varargs : body)) =
     makeVarArgs varargs env params body
eval env (List (Atom "lambda" : varargs@(Atom _) : body)) =
     makeVarArgs varargs env [] body
```

Here is the whole thing in this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/kJj946iR).

Edit2: Well, the question is not a duplicate because it is clearly different.

But for me to miss the `eval env badForm = throwError $ BadSpecialForm "Unrecognized special form" badForm` line, I really must be out of it. The `eval env (List (function : args)) = ...` should also be lower.

I can only conclude that my level of immersion is way too low for this exercise.

At any rate, I see it now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Please include the code that produces that warning.

Comment: There are no overlaps there, AFAICS. Weird warning message. Post the patterns in the actual code.

Comment: Added extra information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why do these pattern matches overlap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336385/why-do-these-pattern-matches-overlap) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648958/haskell-pattern-matches-are-overlapped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eval env (List (function : args)) = do
```

The above overlaps with subsequent patterns, e.g.

```
eval env (List (Atom "define" : List (Atom var : params) : body)) =
```

since `function` can be `Atom "define"` and `args` can be `List (Atom var : params) : body`.

Moreover, the pattern

```
eval env badForm =
```

matches with everything at all. It should be the very last one.

Answer (score 3):

You have:

```
eval env badForm = throwError $ BadSpecialForm "Unrecognized special form" badForm
```

Any clause that comes after this must by necessity have an overlapping pattern. Incidentally, that are the ones the compiler mentions.